# How to set compiler specific flags in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, c++20

I have a code that needs to run with MSVC as well as g++. Therefore I use Cmake. I want to use [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) which are part C++20. Since they exist since C99 they are already in g++ but in MSVC++ they are only available with the flag `/std:latest`.

What's the best way to enable this option for MSVC in a CMake file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post a minimal example of your CMake file to demonstrate what you have tried so far, and any error messages or unexpected behavior you might be getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the variables `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` (applies to release builds only), `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` (applies to debug builds only) and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` (applies to both release and debug).
In case you use also other compilers, you should only set the options for msvc:

```
if(MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /std:latest")
endif()
```

Comment: that's what I needed. Thank you!